# How to write down and check the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, symbolic

This is a simple  touchstone for a serious matter.
I try to solve with Mathematica 13.3.1 on Windows 10  [problem 1278](https://kvant.ras.ru/1991/04/zadachi_m1276_-_m1280.htm) from "The Kvant".
Let real numbers $x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n$ satisfy the conditions $x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0$ and
$x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1.$ Then there exist $i,j,\,$, s.t. $x_ix_j \le -\frac 1 n$.

It is not difficult for small values of $n$, for example,

```
 n = 5; ForAll[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], 
 Implies[Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] == 0 && 
 Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]^2] == 1, 
 Min[Map[#[[1]]*#[[2]] &,Subsets[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], {2}]]] <= -1/n]];
 Resolve[%, Reals] // Timing
```

> `{113.766, True}`

and

```
FindInstance[Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] == 0 && 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]^2] == 1 && 
Min[Map[#[[1]]*#[[2]] &,Subsets[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], {2}]]] > -1/n, 
Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], Reals] // Timing
```

> `{137.219, {}}`

However,

```
Maximize[{Min[Map[#[[1]]*#[[2]] &, Subsets[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], {2}]]], 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] == 0 && 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]^2] == 1}, 
Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] // Timing
```

crashes my comp.
My numerical try for bigger $n$ is as follows.

```
n = 25;NMaximize[{Min[Map[#[[1]]*#[[2]]&,Subsets[Evaluate[Table[x[j],{j, 1, n}]], {2}]]], 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] == 0 && 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]^2] == 1}, Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]]//Timing
```

> `{90.2188, {-0.04, {x[1] -> -0.0408248, x[2] -> 0.979796,  x[3] -> -0.0408248, x[4] -> -0.0408248, x[5] -> -0.0408248,  x[6] -> -0.0408248, x[7] -> -0.0408248, x[8] -> -0.0408248,  x[9] -> -0.0408248, x[10] -> -0.0408248, x[11] -> -0.0408248,  x[12] -> -0.0408248, x[13] -> -0.0408248, x[14] -> -0.0408248,  x[15] -> -0.0408248, x[16] -> -0.0408248, x[17] -> -0.0408248,  x[18] -> -0.0408248, x[19] -> -0.0408248, x[20] -> -0.0408248,  x[21] -> -0.0408248, x[22] -> -0.0408248, x[23] -> -0.0408248,  x[24] -> -0.0408248, x[25] -> -0.0408248}}}`

The above result suggests that an optimal solution is of the form $\min_j x_j \cdot\max_jx_j$
with $x_i=\min_j x_j,\,i \le n-1$ and $x_n=\max_jx_j$. Let us find these minimum and maximum
in the general case  by

```
ClearAll[n]; Solve[(n - 1)*x + y == 0 && (n - 1)*x^2 + y^2 == 1, {x, y}] // FullSimplify
```

> `{{x -> -(1/Sqrt[(-1 + n) n]),  y -> Sqrt[(-1 + n) n]/n}, {x -> 1/Sqrt[(-1 + n) n],  y -> -(Sqrt[(-1 + n) n]/n)}}`

Indeed,

```
x*y /. %[[1]]
```

> `-1/n`

and (One may assume  `x[1] <= x[2] && x[2] <= x[3] && x[3] <= x[4] && x[4] <= x[5]` without loss of generality.)

```
n = 5; FullSimplify[Maximize[{x[1]*x[n], 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] == 0 && 
Total[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]^2] == 1 && x[1] <= x[2] &&
x[2] <= x[3] && x[3] <= x[4] && x[4] <= x[5]}, 
Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]]] // Timing]
```

> `{70.5625, {-(1/5), {x[1] -> -Sqrt[(2/15)], x[2] -> -Sqrt[(2/15)],  x[3] -> -Sqrt[(2/15)], x[4] -> Sqrt[3/10], x[5] -> Sqrt[3/10]}}}`

It is clear that `NMaximize`fails for some big $n$. Also any result of `NMaximize` is only  approximate.

In view of it I'd like to prove that $x_j=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-1) n}},\,j \le n-1,
x_n=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1) n}}{n}$ is an optimal solution of the optimization problem

$${\rm  maximize}\,  x_1x_n $$
under the conditions
$$x_1+x_2+\cdots+x_n=0,\,x_1^2+x_2^2+\cdots+x_n^2=1, $$
$$x_1\le x_2, x_2\le x_3,\dots,x_{n-1}\le x_n.$$

My questions are: how to programmatically write down [the Karush-Kuhn-Tucker conditions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Karush%E2%80%93Kuhn%E2%80%93Tucker+conditions&title=Special:Search&ns0=1)
for that optimization problem in WL as a `Module` which works, say for $n=300$? how to programmatically verify these for $x_j=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{(n-1) n}},\,j \le n-1,
x_n=\frac{\sqrt{(n-1) n}}{n}$ ?

It should be noticed that the KKT conditions seems to be sufficient because of the [concavity](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=Convex+function&title=Special:Search&ns0=1) of the objective function near that point
(Whereas `Min[Map[#[[1]]*#[[2]] &, Subsets[Evaluate[Table[x[j], {j, 1, n}]], {2}]]]` is not concave.).
For example, if $n=3$, then

```
ResourceFunction["HessianMatrix"][x*z, {x, y, z}]
```

> `{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}`

and

```
Resolve[ForAll[{x, y, z}, x < 0 && y < 0 &&  z > 0, {x, y, z} .
{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}} . {x, y, z} <=   0], Reals]
```

> `True`

Comment: It might be a little neater to write the numerical problem using vectors like this:
```obj[v_?(VectorQ[#, NumericQ] &)] := Min[KroneckerProduct[v, v]];
With[{n = 25}, NMaximize[{obj[v], Total[v, 1] == 0, v . v == 1}, v ∈ Vectors[n, Reals]]]```

Comment: @flinty: Thank you for your interest to the problem. Unfortunately, your code produces an incorrect answer `{-0.0509306,{v -> {-0.274626, -0.10541, 
     0.185411, -0.274621, -0.274482, -0.00857918, 0.185453, -0.274599,
      0.185454, 0.185311, 0.185382, 0.185455, -0.274538, 0.1854, 
     0.0833428, 0.185447, 0.185431, 
     0.185455, -0.274625, -0.26953, -0.101443, 0.185439, 0.00819794, 
     0.185433, -0.184159}}}`

Comment: @flinty When `i=j` the product is `x_i^2` which is nonnegative, hence larger than `1/n`. I'm not sure I understand the question at this point, but maybe this rules out `i=j`?

Comment: @flinty: As I understand it, `FindInstance` solves the constraints. This is very slow.

Comment: I don't understand the voice to close the question because "This question doesn’t meet a Mathematica Stack Exchange guideline". What does not meet that guideline?

Comment: If `n` is even then having half the values at `-1/sqrt(n)` and the other half at `1/sqrt(n)` both satisfy the conditions and give `-1/n` as the min for that product. Which means in this case the global max minimizer is not unique. I mention this to point out that this problem could be hard from a computational point of view.